# how to get current route in react-router-dom v4.2.2

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, meteor-react

I want to get current route path in meteor based react project and I want to create login page externally..how can i do it? 
this is my source code

client/main.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import {meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route
} from "react-router-dom"


import "./main.css";
import "../imports/ui/stylesheets/main.scss";

import Main from "../imports/ui/Main";


Meteor.startup(() => {
    return render((
        <Router>
            <Main/>
        </Router>
    ), document.getElementById("app-root"));
});
```

ui/main.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Link, {withRouter} from "react-router-dom"
import PropTypes from "prop-types";


/*@import Templates*/
import Sidebar from "./components/sidebar";

class Main extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <Sidebar/>
                //want current location path for here
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Main;
```

Used versions:

- react v16.2.0
- react-router-dom v4.2.2
- react-router v4.2.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to apply the react router HOC to your component (`withRouter(Main)` at the end of the file) then it'll pass some props to your component, including `match` and `location`.

`match` prop contains `url` and `path` to display the component route (`path` will give you the route with the param name e.g. "user/:id", url give you the real url with the param variable e.g. "user/1d6qsqsd56").

`location.pathname` will give the actual url wherever you call it (gives "/user/1d6qsqsd56" in your sidebar component).

```
class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <Sidebar/>
                <p> Route path : {this.props.location.pathname} </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Main);
```

Edit : Corrected with actual behaviours of different router props.

Comment: @GihanRangana please take a look at my updated answer I made some mistakes before

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the injected property location of the instance of the component like this

```
let currentLocationPath = this.props.location.pathname
```

For more information https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md